# Add a resolved Promise to an object as a property

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm developing a Dapp based on Ethereum and I got stuck with Promises.

In the for loop, the elements of the array have to be verified one by one. This happens at the `validateRow()` function, which returns a Promise at first. The Promise will be resolved to a number (0, when the element is valid; 1, 2 or 3, when it is not valid).

In the end, I would like to return a `resultList[]`, which is an array of objects. Each object should have two properties:

1. `row`, containing the element (a string),
2. and `result`, which tells whether it is valid.

However, the `resultList[]` only contains the rows in the end, while the 'then' branch only holds the results (`{"row":"","result":"0"}`). I added the logs which are printed in the console as comments. Unfortunately, I can't figure out, how I could put the two together.

```
var resultList = [];
for (var i = 0; i < App.resultArray.length; i++) {

    var promiseReturned = contractInstance.validateRow.call(App.resultId, App.resultArray[i]);
    console.log(promiseReturned); //Promise {<pending>}

    var rowObject = new Object();
    console.log(App.resultArray[i]); //row1string
    rowObject.row = App.resultArray[i];

    promiseReturned.then(function(returnVal) {
        console.log("the returnVal: " + returnVal); //the returnVal: 1
        rowObject.result = returnVal;
        console.log("the rowObject :" + JSON.stringify(rowObject)); //{"row":"","result":"0"}
        return returnVal;
        });
        resultList.push(rowObject);
};
console.log(resultList); //[{"row":"row1string"},{"row": "row2string"}]
return resultList;
```

Comment: Objects don't have parameters - only functions have parameters. Objects have *properties*.

Comment: That's right, sorry, corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript, use *forward slashes* to denote comments, not backslashes, else you'll get syntax errors.

Use `Promise.all` to wait for all promises to be resolved before returning the object:

```
async function getResultList() {
  const allPromises = App.resultArray.map((row) => (
    contractInstance.validateRow.call(App.resultId, row)
      .then(result => ({ result, row }))
  ));
  const resultList = await Promise.all(allPromises);
  return resultList; // This will return a Promise to the caller of getResultList
}
```

Note that you'll have to consume `getResultList` as a *promise*, since it doesn't run synchronously. eg

`const resultList = await getResultList();`

Comment: I honestly have no idea why I wrote the comments like that, I think I should go to bed slowly.

So, I guess your recommendation should be the right answer, but it led me to a new problem. When I try to insert your function into my code, I get an error saying 'await is only valid in async function' and I cannot resolve it right now

Comment: See the `async function` at the top? You have to make sure that whatever function the block you posted is in is an async function.

Comment: Yep, but if I just simply add the async keyword to my function, the error still remains, so that's probably a very stupid thing to do. I added my JS code to a fiddle, I'd like to call the function at line 130: https://jsfiddle.net/Antona/16L46xop/9/ Can you probably advise me, how I could correct it?

Comment: You're already using promises and `then`s there, so no need for `await`, just use/return the promise returned by getResultList.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, [CertainPerformance's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49722662/add-a-resolved-promise-to-an-object-as-a-property#answer-49722746) but using `async`/`await`, and rewritten more concisely:

```js
async function getResultList() {
  return await Promise.all(
    App.resultArray.map(async (row) => {
      const result = await contractInstance.validateRow.call(App.resultId, row);
      
      return {
        row,
        result,
      };
    })
  );
}
```